# Need to move node inside another using Nokogiri, then iterate through the node's contents in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, erb, text-parsing

Thanks for reading. Super frustrated (and maybe missing something fundamental, I've never been great with Nokogiri)

In short - I have a source:

```
<div class="schedule-page">
  <h3>Sunday, September 1, 2013</h3>
  <table class="views-table cols-1 schedule-table">
  <div class="game">Game 1</div>
  <div class="game">Game 2</div>
  </table>

  <h3>Sunday, September 7, 2013</h3>
  <table class="views-table cols-1 schedule-table">
  <div class="game">Game 1</div>
  <div class="game">Game 2</div>
  <div class="game">Game 3</div>
  </table>
  <!--and so forth.... -->
</div>
```

I am able to iterate through the source, grab each day and X number of games, and create the container for each day and fields for each game.

```
<% @schedule_array.each do |a_game| %> #

<div class="game-info">

    <div class="date"><%= @the_date %></div>

    <div class="single-game"> # this pulls info for each game, works fine.
        <div class="game-home"><%= a_game.css('.field-home-team').text %></div>
        <div class="game-score"><%= a_game.css('.field-score').text %></div>
        <div class="game-away"><%= a_game.css('.field-away-team').text %></div>
        <div class="game-time"><%= a_game.css('.field-game-date-start-time').text %</div>
    </div>

</div>

<%end%>
```

But I really don't know how to retrieve the original date (h3) from the source and parse it in such a way so that I can use it as shown above.

I've tried a dozen variations of the example shown under Moving Nodes,  here:

http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/modifying_an_html_xml_document.html

But nothing's working. Can anyone tell me the correct way to handle this? My method is gibberish and I'm not sure it's helpful to put it up.

Comment: This is a bit difficult to follow. Your second snippet is using classes that don't exist in your 'source'.

Comment: My bad. I was misunderstanding how Nokogiri works. But thanks anwyays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume @schedule_array is coming from something like `@schedule_array = Nokogiri::HTML( html_contents).css('.schedule-table')`.

In which case, you need to traverse back to the parent and go back to it's previous sibling and get the value:

```
game_date = a_game.parent.previous_element.text
```

So in your particular case, that line can be:

```
<div class="date"><%= a_game.parent.previous_element.text %></div>
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! I was also misunderstanding a bit of how Nokogiri works.